# How to split a 2 part mesh into 2 different meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I have a 3D model of a shotgun that's in 3 parts: The barrel, the chamber door thingy, and then the pump and the stock are in one part. I want to split the stock/pump part into their own individual parts. I can't use bisect because the parts are separate. What do I do?
Here is a pic of my mesh for reference:
[image: model gun in blender]

Comment: dose [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/68393/2217) solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Separation by loose parts

1. Select your mesh. [Right Click]
2. Go into edit mode. <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Separate by loose parts. <kbd>P</kbd> > *By loose parts*

[image: separate by loose parts]

[Manual Entry](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/misc.html#separate)