# how i can select a portion of object in editing mode?

Tags: edit-mode

in this video in minute 33

how i can just select a ring in edit mode when click edit mode select all the top not like the video. please help me if you know easy way to make a wavy effect on the top of donut  tell me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5Gb1VK98Wc

Comment: actually andrew price was a total spoon there because he covered the shortcut display with his face xD

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for the [select loops](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-loops) tool. [My answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68396/2217) lists many different selection tools. Or you could read the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 35:20 in the video he selects an edge loop. The default shortcut for this is `Alt` + `right click`. Note that you need to click on an *edge* and not on a vertex.

[image: Click edge]

[image: Alt Select Mouse]