# How do you seperate two objects?

Tags: modeling

I am currently working on a project, and i've hit an impasse. I was modeling a tree, and just finished. Then I went and made another one. However the two trees that I made are for some reason the same object. It would be greatly appreciated if I could get help on this matter. Thx!

Comment: in Edit mode select the part you want to separate (L will make it easy) and press P > Separate

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68393/how-can-i-select-part-of-a-mesh-and-make-it-seperate